# UIButton with pushViewController that is declared in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Hi everyone I am trying to add a custom nav bar that is declared in a different class and has a button that make a push action.
My initial problem was that when the app was pushing the view because of the uinavicgationconreoller it was crashing, I fixed that somehow and now it also crashes. Here is my code:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@implementation HomeViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TopBar *navBar = [TopBar new];
    [navBar addTopBarToScreen:self.view];
}

-(void)productSheetsButtonFunction
{
    MainViewController* productSheetsView = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:productSheetsView animated:YES];
}
```

and this is my class that hold the method that I call

```
-(void)addTopBarToScreen:(UIView *)screen
{
    //create the top bar
    UIView *topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64.f)];
    topBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [screen addSubview:topBar]


    //add the productSheetsButton
    UIButton *productSheetsButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(96.f, 14.f, 36.f, 36.f)];
    productSheetsButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [productSheetsButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ingredients.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [productSheetsButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ingredients_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [productSheetsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(productSheetsButtonFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [topBar addSubview:productSheetsButton];
}
```

I know that the problem is when i add the target of the button to self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the `addTopBarToScreen` is in another class, that is unrelated to the `HomeViewController` and doesn't have the `productSheetsButtonFunction` defined. You can do this in several ways, but the simplest one, reusing your structure, is to pass the target in the `addTopBarToScreen` method, like this:

```
- (void)addTopBarToScreen:(UIView *)screen target:(id)target
```

Then, in your `addTarget` call you pass that target.

```
 [productSheetsButton addTarget:target 
                         action:@selector(productSheetsButtonFunction) 
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Finally, in your `HomeViewController` you call it like this:

```
[navBar addTopBarToScreen:self.view target:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your action method has the wrong format. It should be of the form:

```
- (void) productSheetsButtonFunction:(id)sender;
```

You then want to refer to it via `@selector(productSheetsButtonFunction:)`

You also seem to create an instance of `TopBar` in `viewDidLoad` which is never used except as a target. However the only reference to this on return is from the button as your original reference goes when `viewDidLoad` returns. It would perhaps be better to make `addTopBarToScreen` a class method and to pass the target and selector in as arguments.

```
+ (void)addTopBarToScreen:(UIView *)screen target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
```

Then from you main code call:

```
[TopBar addTopBarToScreen:self.view target:self action:@selector(productSheetsButtonFunction:))];
```

You need to move `productSheetsButtonFunction:` to be a method of the home controller rather than `TopBar`.